# Where is Shulk Egg Mine?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iii-morrowind

I'm just starting to play Morrowind and it's fantastic! :D

Where can I find Shulk Egg Mine? There's a quest that says I have to go there, but no NPCs have any clues on its location. It's a quest for the fighters guild. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Shulk Egg Mine is just south of Balmora. Follow the river and you can't miss it.

Check out [this map](http://www.uesp.net/maps/mwmap/mwmap.shtml?locx=-21632&locy=-20800&zoom=16) for the exact location.

Comment: You'll want to turn right out of the south gate of Balmora and follow the river in that direction.  The other direction leads back into Balmora, though...so you probably would have figured that out anyway.